# Check if several values are numbers

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple quadratic equation app, the user should enter a three number first: a, b and c.

The first step is checking if all input values are numbers, unfortunately, the function I wrote isn't working. How can I rewrite my function so it console.log 'Input valid data' if the input value is not a number.

```
Here is my code: 

const a_number = parseFloat(prompt("Please, enter a-number", '0'));
const b_number = parseFloat(prompt("Please, enter b-number", '0'));
const c_number = parseFloat(prompt("Please, enter c-number", '0'));
console.log(a_number, b_number, c_number);
ValidInput(a_number, b_number, c_number);

function ValidInput (a, b, c) {
    if (a || b || c) {
        return 
    } else {
        console.log('Invalid input data');
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods) methods like `every`.

Comment: Please use is isNaN provided by javascript. This link be helpful for you https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May use is `isNaN` or `typeof` function:

```
 function ValidInput (a, b, c) {
    if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b) || isNaN(c)) {
       console.log('Invalid input data');
    } else {
       return
    }
  }
```

Comment: isNaN(null) returns false . which is incorrect in case of number.
use `typeof a` ==="number" instead

Comment: for this usecase we wont get null since parseFloat(null) = NaN

Answer (score 2):

You could write your valdiator-function like this:

```
function ValidInput(a, b, c) {
    var argArr = Array.from(arguments);
    return !argArr.some(isNaN);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

```js
const a_number = parseFloat(prompt("Please, enter a-number", '0'));
const b_number = parseFloat(prompt("Please, enter b-number", '0'));
const c_number = parseFloat(prompt("Please, enter c-number", '0'));
console.log(a_number, b_number, c_number);
ValidInput(a_number, b_number, c_number);

function ValidInput (a, b, c) {
    if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b) || isNaN(c)) {
       console.log('Invalid input data');
    } else {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Mind you, your code works even if you enter something which starts with a number and then has some non-numeric characters. For Example, if you type `5.5somethingelse`, `parseFloat` takes the numbers until it hits a non-numeric value. It gets `5.5`

Answer (score 0):

You might also add the parameters your want to test to an array and use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN):

```
ValidInput = (a, b, c) => ![a,b,c].some(isNaN);
```

For example:

```js
ValidInput = (a, b, c) => ![a, b, c].some(isNaN);

if (!ValidInput(1, "a", 3)) {
  console.log('Invalid input data');
}
```